# Can I take an extra piece of luggage to the USA?

Tags: usa, luggage, qatar-airways

I am flying to the USA from Bangladesh on Qatar Airways on 25 October. I know that I am allowed to take only 2 pieces of luggage at a time, but I want to take an extra one. How much would I have to pay per kilogram?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Qatar airways website?

Answer (score 3):

The rates for your flight are per piece of luggage, not per kilogram.  And they're steep, at 200 USD if purchased online (in advance) and 250 USD otherwise.  Even more if your bags are over 22 kg.

From here: http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/excess-baggage-rates.page

Comment: @Willeke: clarified.